# getpwnam("www") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server

I copied the [nginx.conf](http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample) sample onto my ubuntu 12.04 box (I don't know where to put the other conf files. I'm an nginx noob). When I try to start nginx I get the following error:

```
abe-lens-laptop@abe:/etc$ sudo service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("www") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix it? I found this post but my user is already set to www www (if you see in the linked file) [How do I change the NGINX user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/433265/how-do-i-change-the-nginx-user)

Comment: Link to nginx.config is broken

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The user you specified in your configuration, `www`, doesn't exist. Either create the user, or choose a user that does exist.

Comment: the syntax is: useradd www

Comment: work's for me on centos 7, thx!

Answer (score 12):

Your other option (if you don't want to create a new user) is to replace the user field in nginx.conf with:

```
user nobody;
```

Comment: I received the following error `getgrnam("nobody") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1`

Answer (score 7):

Create the `www` user. On Ubuntu this should be done using the following command and flags:

```
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --shell /bin/false --group --disabled-login www
```

Answer (score 4):

nginx version: nginx/1.13.9 
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

just use

```
user  nobody nogroup;
```

Comment: I had same problem, after changing php-fpm user and group i had changed nginx user to my user but i was referring to old guide and this answer helped to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While Michael Hamptons answer is correct, it is only part of the answer. A more complete version would be:

1. Check if the user exists
2. Also check which user you use to start the docker container

If you do:

```
docker -u 0 ....
```

then the same message will appear even if the user exists on the host system. Changing the value behind -u to the id of user nginx then solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command that's work for me "Scientific Linux"

```
adduser  --no-create-home  --system  --user-group --shell /bin/false   www
```

or the user name   `www-data` if you use it instead

```
adduser  --no-create-home  --system  --user-group --shell /bin/false   www-data
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue... I chose "nginx" user and it didn't exist. I solved it reconfiguring and recompiling NGINX choosing an existing one.

*./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --user=myUser --group=myUsergroup*

Everything is OK now...

Comment: Compilation options are a way to set **default** values for some directives. It's of course not necessary to compile nginx again to change these : these default values are overloaded by configuration files.

Comment: Of course, but we're talking about the first time confguration/compilation...

Comment: Where did you read that exactly? First configuration has nothing to do with compilation btw.